# Confused about Cholesky and eigen decomposition

Tags: matrix-decomposition, eigenvalues, cholesky-decomposition

I'm looking to generate correlated random variables. I have a symmetric, positive definite matrix. So I know that you can use the Cholesky decomposition, however I keep being told that this only works for Gaussian random variables?! Is that true?

Furthermore how does this compare to Eigen decomposition. For example using Cholesky decomposition we can write a random parameter as:

$x = \bar{x} + Lz$

where $L$ is the Cholesky decomposition (lower/upper triangular matrix) and $z$ is some vector of random variables. So one can sample the $z$'s and build up a pdf of x. Now we could also use Eigen decomposition and write x as:

$x = \bar{x} + U\lambda^{1\over2}z$

where $\lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues and $U$ is a matrix composed of the eigenvalues. So we could also build a pdf of this. But if we equate these $x$'s we find that $L = U\lambda^{1\over2}$ But this isn’t true as $L$ is triangular and $U\lambda^{1\over2}$ is not?! So I'm really, really confused. So to clarify the questions:

1) For Cholesky decomposition does the vector z have to be only Gaussian?
2) How does the eigenvalue compare with the Cholesky decomposition? They are clearly different factorisation techniques. So I don't see how the $x$'s above can be equivalent?

Thanks, as always, guys.

Comment: (1) No, any distribution. (2) Hmm, I'm not mathematician. As I know the two decompositions are indeed quite different. `Composed of the eigenvalues` Did you mean "eigenvectors"? BTW, it is possible to generate the variables you want also via principal components, with the help of eigenvalues and eigenvectors. But, sorry, I failed to understand what you imply by the two formulas you showed.

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](http://sciencemeanderthal.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/cholesky-decomposition-of-variance-covariance-matrices-in-the-classic-twin-study). Hope this helps.

Comment: It's a theorem that if $x$ has a multivariate normal distribution, and we multiply $y=Ax$, then $y$ will also have a multivariate normal distribution.  However, if $x$ has some other distribution then the distribution of $y$ need not be of the same family as the distribution of $x$. However, the method that you've described will ensure that you get the desired covariance.

Comment: How about reading [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40316331/4891738) at Stack Overflow: [Obtain vertices of the ellipse on an ellipse covariance plot (created by `car::ellipse`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40316331/4891738). Although the question is asked in different application, the theory behind is the same. You will see nice figures for geometric explanation there.

Answer (score 7):

1) Pretty much yes.  The reason is that the $x_i$'s are going to end up being a linear combination of the $z_i$'s.  That works out nicely for Gaussian deviates because any linear combination of Gaussian deviates is, itself, a Gaussian deviate.  Unfortunately, this is not necessarily true of other distributions.

2) It's a little puzzling, I know, but they are equivalent.  Let $\Sigma$ be your covariance matrix and suppose you have both the Cholesky factorization, $\Sigma=L L^T$ and the eigendecomposition, $\Sigma=U \lambda U^T$.  The covariance of $L z$ is given by:
$$
\begin{array}{}
E[L z (L z)^T] & = & E[L z z^T L^T] \\
& = & L \ E[z z^T] \ L^T \\
& = & L \ I \ L^T \\
& = & L L^T \\
& = & \Sigma 
\end{array}
$$
Similarly, the covariance of $U \lambda^\frac{1}{2} z$ is given by:
$$
\begin{array}{}
E[U \lambda^\frac{1}{2} z (U \lambda^\frac{1}{2} z)^T] & = & E[U \lambda^\frac{1}{2} z z^T \lambda^\frac{1}{2} U^T] \\
& = & U \lambda^\frac{1}{2} \ E[z z^T] \ \lambda^\frac{1}{2} U^T \\
& = & U \lambda^\frac{1}{2} \ I \ \lambda^\frac{1}{2} U^T \\
& = & U \lambda^\frac{1}{2} \lambda^\frac{1}{2} U^T \\
& = & U \lambda U^T \\
& = & \Sigma 
\end{array}
$$
For purposes of computation, I suggest you stick with the Cholesky factorization unless your covariance matrix is ill-conditioned/nearly singular/has a high condition number.  Then it's probably best to switch to the eigendecomposition.

Comment: Oh, I should add that this technique works for ANY factorization of $\Sigma = F F^T$.  And this factorization is not unique unless you force $F$ to be lower triangular (in which case, $F$ is the Cholesky factor).

Comment: Nice answer which is spot on together with the comment.